# Unable to reboot after new installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lts, macbook-pro

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Macbook Pro 8,2 using a LiveUSB. To even start ubuntu, I had to edit the command line to try or install ubuntu to use nomodeset.

The installation runs fine, and I have made sure my boot order is ok by using "sudo efibootmgr" in terminal. I wanted to edit /etc/default/grub by adding nomodeset, but it would not let me update saying: error:failed to get canonical path of /cow.

Then when I reboot it shows a purple square filled with black, then turns black and shows this message: [6.052140] Disabling IRQ #17

After that I don't get a response, when I try to install it again from the LiveUSB it shows that Ubuntu is already installed.

The Macbook is old, battery is dead, and it wouldn't even reinstall OS X Lion, i was hoping to revive it using Ubuntu. If it would be a better idea to just give up on it please let me know.